# Is there a way to auto generate a __str__() implementation in python?

Tags: python, boilerplate

Being tired manually implementing a string representation for my classes, I was wondering if there is a pythonic way to do that automatically.

I would like to have an output that covers all the attributes of the class and the class name. Here is an example:

```
class Foo(object):
    attribute_1 = None
    attribute_2 = None
    def __init__(self, value_1, value_2):
         self.attribute_1 = value_1
         self.attribute_2 = value_2
```

Resulting in:

```
bar = Foo("baz", "ping")
print(str(bar)) # desired: Foo(attribute_1=baz, attribute_2=ping)
```

This question came to mind after using Project Lombok [@ToString](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString.html) in some Java projects.

Comment: What Project Lombok does for Java?

Comment: Boilerplate code reduction. Look here for features: https://projectlombok.org/features/index.html

Comment: Actually, "boilerplate code reduction" means nothing. Lombok deals with specific Java problems. It is useless to search for "similar" tool, it's better to ask for something more concrete.

Comment: Python *has* a default implementation for `__str__`, which forwards to `__repr__`. `__repr__` also has a default implementation, which mentions the results of `type(my_object)` and `id(my_object)`. If you want to use some other default, you could a) use inheritance, b) write your own class decorator, or c) assign `__str__` in the class body to some existing function (by doing `__str__ = something` rather than `def __str__(self)`).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can iterate instance attributes using [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars), [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir), ...:

```
def auto_str(cls):
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s(%s)' % (
            type(self).__name__,
            ', '.join('%s=%s' % item for item in vars(self).items())
        )
    cls.__str__ = __str__
    return cls

@auto_str
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, value_1, value_2):
        self.attribute_1 = value_1
        self.attribute_2 = value_2
```

Applied:

```
>>> str(Foo('bar', 'ping'))
'Foo(attribute_2=ping, attribute_1=bar)'
```

Comment: This does not work for complex class attributes like List[MyClass]

Comment: @Sniper, Yeah, this solution does not recurse. How about using dataclasses?

Comment: BTW, Did you `@auto_str` decorate `MyClass`?

Comment: Yes I did(Comment must be 15 char in length :| )

Comment: @Sniper, Replacing `__str__`s with `__repr__`s will give you what you want. (`list` uses `__repr__` to represent list items as string, not `__str__`)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [@dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), which automatically generates `__init__()`, `__repr__()`, `__str__()`, and more. You just need to add a `@dataclass` decorator to your class and add type annotations to the members. You can even remove your `__init__()` implementation then.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Foo(object):
    attribute_1 : str
    attribute_2 : str

bar = Foo("baz", "ping")
print(str(bar)) # Prints: Foo(attribute_1='baz', attribute_2='ping')
```

Answer (score 2):

wrote this while falsetru answerred.
Its the same idea, mine is very beginner friendly in terms of reading it, his is much nicer implemented imho

```
class stringMe(object):
        def __str__(self):
            attributes = dir(self)
            res = self.__class__.__name__ + "("
            first = True
            for attr in attributes:
                if attr.startswith("__") and attr.endswith("__"):
                    continue

                if(first):
                    first = False
                else:
                    res += ", "

                res += attr + " = " + str( getattr(self, attr))

            res += ")"
            return res

    class Foo(stringMe):
        attribute_1 = None
        attribute_2 = None
        def __init__(self, value_1, value_2):
             self.attribute_1 = value_1
             self.attribute_2 = value_2


bar = Foo("baz", "ping")
print(str(bar)) # desired: Foo(attribute_1=baz, attribute_2=ping)
```