# Proper autogenerate of __str__() implementation also for sqlalchemy classes?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, boilerplate

I would like to display / print my sqlalchemy classes nice and clean.

In [Is there a way to auto generate a `__str__()` implementation in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32910096/is-there-a-way-to-auto-generate-a-str-implementation-in-python/33800667)
 the answer [You can iterate instance attributes using vars, dir, ...:...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33800620/10698244) helps in the case of simple classes.

When I try to apply it to a `Sqlalchemy` class (like the one from 
[Introductory Tutorial of Python’s SQLAlchemy](https://www.pythoncentral.io/introductory-tutorial-python-sqlalchemy/) - see below), I get - apart from the member variables also the following entry as a member variable:

`_sa_instance_state=<sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x000000004CEBCC0>`

How can I avoid that this entry appears in the `__str__` representation?

For the sake of completeness, I put the solution of the linked stackoverflow question below, too.

```
import os
import sys
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

Base = declarative_base()

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    # Here we define columns for the table person
    # Notice that each column is also a normal Python instance attribute.
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
```

As mentioned, this is the solution from [Is there a way to auto generate a `__str__`() implementation in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32910096/is-there-a-way-to-auto-generate-a-str-implementation-in-python/33800667):

```
def auto_str(cls):
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s(%s)' % (
            type(self).__name__,
            ', '.join('%s=%s' % item for item in vars(self).items())
        )
    cls.__str__ = __str__
    return cls

@auto_str
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, value_1, value_2):
        self.attribute_1 = value_1
         self.attribute_2 = value_2
```

Applied:

```
>>> str(Foo('bar', 'ping'))
'Foo(attribute_2=ping, attribute_1=bar)'
```

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55713664/11163122

Comment: 2024 update: SQLAlchemy 2.0 now supports ORM objects as [dataclasses](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/dataclasses.html)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is what I use:

```
def todict(obj):
    """ Return the object's dict excluding private attributes, 
    sqlalchemy state and relationship attributes.
    """
    excl = ('_sa_adapter', '_sa_instance_state')
    return {k: v for k, v in vars(obj).items() if not k.startswith('_') and
            not any(hasattr(v, a) for a in excl)}

class Base:

    def __repr__(self):
        params = ', '.join(f'{k}={v}' for k, v in todict(self).items())
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({params})"

Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)
```

Any models that inherit from `Base` will have the default `__repr__()` method defined and if I need to do something different I can just override the method on that particular class.

It excludes the value of any private attributes denoted with a leading underscore, the SQLAlchemy instance state object, and any relationship attributes from the string. I exclude the relationship attributes as I most often don't want the repr to cause a relationship to lazy load, and where the relationship is bi-directional, including relationship attribs can cause infinite recursion.

The result looks like: `ClassName(attr=val, ...)`.

--EDIT--

The `todict()` func that I mention above is a helper that I often call upon to construct a `dict` out of a SQLA object, mostly for serialisation. I was lazily using it in this context but it isn't very efficient as it's constructing a `dict` (in `todict()`) to construct a `dict` (in `__repr__()`). I've since modified the pattern to call upon a generator:

```
def keyvalgen(obj):
    """ Generate attr name/val pairs, filtering out SQLA attrs."""
    excl = ('_sa_adapter', '_sa_instance_state')
    for k, v in vars(obj).items():
        if not k.startswith('_') and not any(hasattr(v, a) for a in excl):
            yield k, v
```

Then the base Base looks like this:

```
class Base:

    def __repr__(self):
        params = ', '.join(f'{k}={v}' for k, v in keyvalgen(self))
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({params})"
```

The `todict()` func leverages off of the `keyvalgen()` generator as well but isn't needed to construct the repr anymore.

Comment: Nice --EDIT-- and a clean implementation.

Comment: how abt just define __str__() rather than __repl__() ? This question seems just wanna print a sqlalchemy object.

Answer (score 11):

I define this `__repr__` method on my base model, or in a mixin:

```py
def __repr__(self):
    package = self.__class__.__module__
    class_ = self.__class__.__name__
    attrs = sorted((k, getattr(self, k)) for k in self.__mapper__.columns.keys())
    sattrs = ', '.join(f'{key}={value!r}' for key, value in attrs)
    return f'{package}.{class_}({sattrs})'
```

The method displays the names of all of a table's columns (but not relationships), and the `repr` of their values, in alphabetical order.  I wouldn't usually define `__str__` unless I need a particular form - perhaps `str(User(name='Alice'))` would just be `Alice` - so `str(model_instance)` will call the `__repr__` method.

#### Sample code

```py
import datetime

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm


class ReprMixin:
    """Provide a default __repr__ for ORM model classes."""

    def __repr__(self):
        package = self.__class__.__module__
        class_ = self.__class__.__name__
        attrs = sorted((k, getattr(self, k)) for k in self.__mapper__.columns.keys())
        sattrs = ', '.join(f'{key}={value!r}' for key, value in attrs)
        return f'{package}.{class_}({sattrs})'


Base = orm.declarative_base()


class MyModel(ReprMixin, Base):

    __tablename__ = 'mytable'

    foo = sa.Column(sa.String(32))
    bar = sa.Column('bar_id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    baz = sa.Column(sa.DateTime)
```

```
>>> mm = models.MyModel(foo='Foo', bar=42, baz=datetime.datetime.now())
>>> mm
models.MyModel(bar=42, baz=datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 4, 7, 37, 59, 350432), foo='Foo')
```

---

The original version of this answer used the model's `__table__` attribute to access the column names.  I've changed it to use the model's `__mapper__` instead because SQLAlchemy allows the model attribute name (stored in the mapper) to be different from the column name in the database (stored in the table).  `MyModel.bar` demonstrates this.