# SQLAlchemy best way to define __repr__ for large tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, repr

I have a bunch of tables in SQLAlchemy that I want to define `__repr__`.

The standard convention seems to look like this:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "<TableName(id='%s')>" % self.id
```

This is all well and good for small tables.  However, I have tables with 40+ columns.  **Is there a better way of constructing `__repr__` such that I am not manually typing out a massive string?**

My file housing all tables is called `models.py`.  One solution I thought about was making a method `_create_repr_string` in `models.py` that takes care of auto-generating the string for `__repr__` to return.  I am wondering if there is a more standard way to create `__repr__`.

Comment: Hi I recently answered a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54034230/6560549

Comment: Take a look at this ReprMixin that you can add to your base class: https://github.com/absent1706/sqlalchemy-mixins#beauty-__repr__

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Having good `__repr__` for complex objects can be incredibly useful when navigating log files and stacktraces, so it's great that you're trying to come up with a good pattern for it.

I like to have a little helper with a default (BaseModel gets set as the `model_class` when initializing `flask-sqlalchemy` in my case).

```
import typing
import sqlalchemy as sa

class BaseModel(Model):

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self._repr(id=self.id)

    def _repr(self, **fields: typing.Dict[str, typing.Any]) -> str:
        '''
        Helper for __repr__
        '''
        field_strings = []
        at_least_one_attached_attribute = False
        for key, field in fields.items():
            try:
                field_strings.append(f'{key}={field!r}')
            except sa.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError:
                field_strings.append(f'{key}=DetachedInstanceError')
            else:
                at_least_one_attached_attribute = True
        if at_least_one_attached_attribute:
            return f"<{self.__class__.__name__}({','.join(field_strings)})>"
        return f"<{self.__class__.__name__} {id(self)}>"
```

Now you can keep your `__repr__` methods nice and neat:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):

    def __repr__(self):
        # easy to override, and it'll honor __repr__ in foreign relationships
        return self._repr(id=self.id,
                          user=self.user,
                          blah=self.blah)
```

Should produce something like:

`<MyModel(id=1829,user=<User(id=21, email='foo@bar.com')>,blah='hi')>`

Comment: I like the customizability of this method, thank you!

Comment: I wanted to implement your helper in flask but ran into the following error:
```sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper mapped class BaseModel->base_model could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'base_model'```

Is there a beginner-friendly explanation how to implement your helper without running into this error?

Comment: @p6l-richard Inherit your class from both the usual `sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()` *and* the `BaseModel` class that Stephen Fuhry has written. The `BaseModel` itself does not need to inherit from `Model` - it can be stand-alone.

Comment: `**fields: typing.Dict[str, typing.Any]` probably must be just `**fields: typing.Any`.