# sqlalchemy with MariaDB cant get all rows

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mariadb

I am new to SQLAlchemy.  I am trying to make it work with a MariaDB.  I am trying to get all the records from the DB and cant seem to get the correct syntax for this.

I have tried Employee.query.all(), and other variations and none seem to work for me.  I either get an error with 'all' attribute or with the the 'query' attribute

```
  all_employee = session.query.all(Employee)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'all'
```

############################# CODE ##############################

```
# Define the MariaDB engine using MariaDB Connector/Python
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f"mariadb+pymysql://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASS}@{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB}")

Base = declarative_base()

class Employee(Base):

   __tablename__ = 'employees'
   id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True)
   firstname = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(length=100))
   lastname = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(length=100))
   active = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Boolean, default=True)


class EmployeeSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        #all fields from DB
        fields = ('id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'active')

#creates db model
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

#initialize Session
Session = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)
session = Session()


employee_schema = EmployeeSchema()


#Get Employee
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_employee():
    all_employee = session.query.all(Employee)
    app.logger.info(f"employees is {str(all_employee)}")
    result = employee_schema.dump(all_employee)
    return jsonify(result)
```

Comment: `session.query(Employee).all()`

Comment: When I do that I get a blank dictionary and when I print out the contents it just memory id's, not any readable data.

Comment: @TexiaPlazaola, do you mean your `logger.info` statement prints `{}`? Also, I can't find any reference to the `.dump()` function in the sqlalchemy docs, are you using marshmallow or similar serialization library to get that function?

Comment: Yes I am using Marshmallow and jsonify, but I didn't include the rest of the code.  Only the function that I am having an issue with.  The logger.info statement prints a whole bunch of memory id's

Comment: The  "memory ids" are the default representations of the objects.  Try `app.logger.info(f"employees is {str([e.lastname for e in all_employee])}")`.  If you are getting objects in the schema dump there is something wrong with the schema definition

Comment: That worked.  I got the last names.  How can I then get all the info?  Do I need to use a loop or can I get all the info with .all() attribute?

Comment: You already have all the  info in the model instances returned by `.all()`.  If you want to see the data in your logs you can add a `__repr__` method to your models, as described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54026174/5320906), for example.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**:
Looked through the [marshmallow docs](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshmallow.schema.html#marshmallow.schema.Schema.dump) and found that there is a keyword argument you can pass to the `dump()` function: `many`. This will treat your passed-in object as a collection rather than a single object (which is the reason you were getting the "empty dict" object). This should return you a JSON-able list of dicts.

```py
#...snip...

#Get Employee
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_employee():
    all_employee = session.query(Employee).all()
    app.logger.info(f"employees is {[e.__dict__ for e in all_employee]}")
    result = employee_schema.dump(all_employee, many=True)
    return jsonify(result)
```

---

If you look at the [SQL Alchemy docs on Querying](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html), I think you just have a slight syntax error. `query` is a method/function, which is why you are getting the `'function' object has no attribute 'all'` when you attempt to access the `all()` member function.

```py
session.query.all(Employee)
```

should work instead as

```py
session.query(Employee).all()
```

I suggest poking around the SQL Alchemy docs for a while if you're just learning it, they are really exhaustive and well structured!

Comment: Already tried that, but not really much info on MariaDB.  Most of the stuff is with SQLLite.  Most of the stuff we do is mostly on MariaDB.

Comment: @TexiaPlazaola hope you figure out your issue, lmk if the above edit worked for you.

Comment: Yes the edit worked for me.  Thanks,

Comment: Glad to hear it! Would you mind setting this answer to the accepted one?